# Selenium показывает не всю страницу, охватывая не весь тег

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bs4

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/'
driver.get(url)
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
name = soup.head
if "text/javascript" in name:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
print(name)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe "D:/Project python/Parser Dns.py" 
False
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="10;URL=/ciez2a" http-equiv="refresh"/>
</head>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

А вот так должен выглядеть код

[image: А вот так должен выглядеть код]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в своем коде Selenium и не используете - html страницы вы получаете с помощью requests, а не Selenium.

Попробуйте так:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/'
driver.get(url)
page_html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')
name = soup.head
if "text/javascript" in name:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
print(name)
```